# What is the short cut key for command line auto complete?

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts

I am running Ubuntu 13.10. When I log in through remote desktop and use the terminal, I cannot use the <kbd>tab</kbd> key to auto complete the command for items such as files/directories. The remote window manager is xfce, and the terminal shell is bash.

If I access the same box using SSH, I can use <kbd>tab</kbd> key to auto complete.

What is the key for auto complete command for the terminal emulator in xfce window? The regular <kbd>tab</kbd> key does not work.

Comment: Have the sshd_config parameters been modified? It sounds like the SSH daemon is not allowing your session to envoke environment settings/variables and shell profile/rc.

Comment: The tab key works with SSH remote shell, but it is not working if I tried to auto complete the command for Terminal emulator in XFCE desktop window.  How do I modify the sshd_config parameters?

Comment: The SSH Daemon config file is `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` However, this may not be the problem. I would make a backup of that file before you do anything else. You may also wish to restore the original default version of the file in case anything has been changed that caused this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you install the remmina package to connect (basically an alternative Remote Desktop) it has a feature to send all keyboard codes to the remote client.

source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1876244